# How to create table with geometry column in GPKG with spatialite?

Tags: spatialite, geopackage

I want to create a vectorial GPKG with spatialite.

With the help of the documenation (here: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html#p16gpkg ), I've created a `sql` script that look like this:

```sql
SELECT EnableGpkgMode();
SELECT gpkgCreateBaseTables();

CREATE TABLE grid ('fid' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);
SELECT gpkgAddGeometryColumn('grid', 'geom', 'GEOMETRY', 0, 0, 4326);
```

Here is my output:

```
$ rm -f test.gpkg && spatialite test.gpkg < test.sql
SpatiaLite version ..: 4.3.0a   Supported Extensions:
    - 'VirtualShape'    [direct Shapefile access]
    - 'VirtualDbf'      [direct DBF access]
    - 'VirtualXL'       [direct XLS access]
    - 'VirtualText'     [direct CSV/TXT access]
    - 'VirtualNetwork'  [Dijkstra shortest path]
    - 'RTree'       [Spatial Index - R*Tree]
    - 'MbrCache'        [Spatial Index - MBR cache]
    - 'VirtualSpatialIndex' [R*Tree metahandler]
    - 'VirtualElementary'   [ElemGeoms metahandler]
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
    - 'VirtualFDO'      [FDO-OGR interoperability]
    - 'VirtualGPKG' [OGC GeoPackage interoperability]
    - 'VirtualBBox'     [BoundingBox tables]
    - 'SpatiaLite'      [Spatial SQL - OGC]
PROJ.4 version ......: Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
GEOS version ........: 3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771
TARGET CPU ..........: x86_64-linux-gnu
the SPATIAL_REF_SYS table already contains some row(s)


Error: near line 5: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The database seems to require that there is a corresponding line in the gpkg_contents table before you can add the gpkg geometry field. Do something like this before SELECT gpkgAddGeometryColumn

```
insert into gpkg_contents values
('grid','features','grid','description','2018-05-03',0,0,360,90,4326);
```

I am not sure if the syntax is totally correct. I also guess that `SELECT gpkgAddGeometryTriggers('grid','geom')` would be good to execute in some place and triggers should perhaps update the gpkg_contents table automatically. However, it did not seem to happen but I did not spend much time for testing.

This thread in spatialite-users forum may give some more information https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/D0MV4Z3k0-E.

Answer (score 1):

1: Maybe it's constraint to srs_ref (4326)
after `SELECT gpkgCreateBaseTables()` trow
`select gpkgInsertEpsgSRID(4326)` allows to populate the gpkg_spatial_ref_sys table.

2: In your create table create geom column with a geometry type, like:
`create table grid ("fid" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "geom" MULTIPOLYGON)`

3: Add table to gpkg_contents
`insert into gpkg_contents values ('grid','features','grid','description','2018-05-03',0,0,360,90,4326);`

4: Refer to that geom column and type in
`select gpkgAddGeometryColumn("grid", "geom" , "MULTIPOLYGON", 0 , 0, 4326 )`

param function:

```
gpkgAddGeometryColumn( table_name String, geometry_column_name String , geometry_type String , with_z Integer , with_m Integer , srs_id Integer ) : void
```

geometry_type is a normal WKT name:

```
"GEOMETRY","POINT","LINESTRING","POLYGON","MULTIPOINT","MULTILINESTRING","MULTIPOLYGON","GEOMCOLLECTION"
```

ref here: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html?